# Linux iptables forwarding

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, forwarding, traffic

I've 3 machines :

- 1 server with LAN card without internet direct access
- 1 Windows host with WiFi connection for Internet and 1 LAN port
- 1 linux virtual machine on the Windows host

[Server_without_internet]---[Linux_VM]---[Windows_host]

- Server_without_internet : eth0 -> 192.168.1.1
- Linux_VM_WiFi_NAT : wlan0 -> 10.0.2.15
- Linux_VM_LAN_bridge_card : eth0 -> 192.168.1.254
- Windows_LAN : 192.168.1.2
- Windows_WiFi : 172.16.1.1 / 10.0.2.1(NAT Linux to 10.0.2.15)

I want to use iptables forwarding to have Internet access to [Server_without_Internet].

Routes :

- Server_without_internet, Linux_VM_LAN_bridge_card, Windows_LAN : 192.168.1.0/24 via 192.168.1.254
- Linux_VM_WiFi_NAT : 0.0.0.0 via 10.0.2.1 (172.16.1.1)

I enable IPv4 forwarding :

```
sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

I configure iptables to Linux_VM same as :

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o wlan0 -j MASQUERADE 
iptables -A FORWARD -i wlan0 -o eth0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0-o wlan0 -j ACCEPT
```

Ping :

- Ping OK : 192.168.1.1 to 1.2
- Ping OK : 192.168.1.1 to 1.254
- Ping OK : 192.168.1.2 to 1.1
- Ping OK : 192.168.1.2 to 1.254
- Ping OK : 192.168.1.254 to 1.1
- Ping OK : 192.168.1.254 to 1.2
- Ping OK : 10.0.2.15 to 8.8.8.8
- Ping OK : 172.16.1.1 / 10.0.2.1 to 8.8.8.8
- Ping KO : 192.168.1.1 to 8.8.8.8

Remind I try to have internet access since [Server_without_server] via [Linux_VM]

When I check with tcpdump on Linux_VM:

- tcpdump -i eth0 -vvnn : I see the echo request to 8.8.8.8
- tcpdump -i wlan0 -vvnn : I see the echo request to 8.8.8.8 but not echo reply

So the eth0 forwarding to wlan0 with iptables work but I not have the return.

Someone have an idea ?

Thanks

EDIT

I add the conntrack iptables cli and the IP public icmp test work.

```
iptables -A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

Now the DNS resolver doesn't work. In the server /etc/resolv.conf, I had Google DNS and OpenDNS DNS.

An idea ?

THanks

Comment: Which kind of virtual machine platform di you use? Does it offer ICMP on its networking? Eg virtualbox with "user mode" networking doesn't.

Comment: @Ralph : Virtualbox yes, but also wget doesn't work

Do I have to install a local dns on the Linux (Linux_VM) server and use this one on my server (server_without_internet)?

Comment: Now the DNS resolver doesn't work. In the server /etc/resolv.conf, I had Google DNS and OpenDNS DNS.